# How do I make a WPF ListView shrink?

Tags: wpf, layout

Ok this is really making me crazy and I need some help.

I have a listview with an itemssource that has several gridviewcolumns. When the ItemsSource gets set, the columns size to fit the contents.

Whenever I increase the width by grabbing the column it makes the listview grow, but when I decrease the width it **does not shrink**. According [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122746/wpf-listview-grows-wider-in-response-to-resizing-column-but-does-not-shrink-back) this is per WPF layout process.

I subclassed the ListView to override this behavior and can't get it to work right.

I have overridden the MeasureOverride function like so:

```
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
            var size = base.MeasureOverride(constraint);

            var gv = this.View as GridView;

            if (gv != null)
            {
                var width = gv.Columns.Select(a => a.ActualWidth).ToArray();
                size.Width = gv.Columns.Sum(a => a.ActualWidth) ;
                if (scroll.ScrollableHeight > 0)
                    size.Width += SystemParameters.ScrollWidth;
            }

            return size;
    }
```

Which does cause the listview to shrink as desired, but **if the listview has a vertical scrollbar it disappears.** 
I can't figure out how to get the scrollbar to come back programmatically.

Now if I then increase the width beyond the original width the scrollbar comes back(but this is through the UI not code. I just have been playing with this for longer than I care to admit and I'm lost.

Anyone have any idea what I should do besides quit trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is even a problem is because of the very nature of a `ScrollViewer`, it keeps the size of it's content, so when the `ListView` shrinks via a `MeasureOverride`, it's content still remains the same. The solution below is not perfect, but it is the best I could find. If there is a better one please let me know.

The solution I arrived at was to keep the `MeasureOverride` function as above and also overriding `ArrangeOverride` and set the width of the `ScrollViewer` to be the final width of the `ListView` like so:

```
public Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
{
  var size = base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
  var scroll = GetScrollViewer();
  scroll.Width = size.Width;
  return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a better way, just the trickiest one.

You can have a dependency property on your code behind that's equal to the sum of the ActualWidth of all your ListViewColumns plus the scroll width if there is a scroll and bind the listView Width property to this dependency property.

But you'll just have to update this property everytime a column changes size. Hopefully that's not to often.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken the `ListView` has its own `ScrollViewer` which is accessed via attached properties, so if you want to change that in code you probably need to do it like this:

```
lv.SetValue(ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty,
            ScrollBarVisibility.Visible);
```

Of how much help that is i do not know though.

(*`lv` is a ListView instance, if you are in a subclass you will probably just use `this`*)