# WPF layout: elements growing, but not shrinking correctly

Tags: wpf, xaml, resize, autoresize

I have a following XAML code (also filled with some dummy content to demonstrate the issue):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfWatchBird.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="378" Width="728"
        Name="frmMainList">
    <Grid Name="grdMainLayout">
        <ListBox Name="lstData" SelectionChanged="lstData_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBoxItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListBoxItem.Content>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Label Content="nick" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Teal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0" Padding="0"/>
                        <Label Content="kategória" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Green" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" Padding="0"/>
                        <Label Content="stav záznamu" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Padding="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
                        <Label Content="1.1. 2013 12:00" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" Padding="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"/>

                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Source="http://www.birdz.sk/la/bezfotky.gif" />
                        <StackPanel x:Name="spItemText" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=spItemText,Path=ActualWidth}" FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                <TextBlock.Text>Nadpis blogu, konečne, dámy a páni :)</TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" xml:space="preserve" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                                       Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                       MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=spItemText, Path=ActualWidth}">
                                <TextBlock.Text>Preview textu blogu, blablabla, blabla, bude to pekné a krásne
a bude to vedieť robiť aj newliny, len ešte nejak spraviť zarovnanie, aby nebolo... aha, ono nie je, on mi len kvôli xml:space preserve... A už mi aj krásne funguje textwrapping, keď som poodstraňoval zopár nepotrebných
...hmm... tak jeden riadok to wraplo dobre, ale ten ďalší už nie, zaujímavé...
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                            <Hyperlink>Otvor originál</Hyperlink>
                        </Label>
                        <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Hyperlink>Otvor zložku so zálohou</Hyperlink>
                        </Label>
                    </Grid>
                </ListBoxItem.Content>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Menu 2" />
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When growing the window, it resizes correctly, but upon shrinking it refuses to do so. I have found [this question which seems very much related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122746/), but I don't consider the answer in there to be a proper answer (also, I can't comment on questions/answers, otherwise, I'd write it there).

The "answer" says that by default ItemsControls are grow-only, **but the "by default" suggests there is a way to override this**, however the answer doesn't explain how this is done and I can't find anything about it... Any ideas? I'd like to do it in XAML, it should be possible without codebehind hacks, IMO...

Comment: Try setting `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` on the list box.

Comment: @XAMeLi Thank you very much Sir, would you kindly write it again not as a comment, but an answer so I can mark it as the correct one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` on the list box.

The reason is that scroll viewer (that is part of the template of `ListBox`) will "prefer" to open a horizontal scroll bar than to shrink the content.

Comment: Man, I spent half a day trying to overflow a TextBlock text in a TreeViewItem with no luck. I didn't even know what to search for on the web. I had the `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` set on `Hidden` instead of `Disabled`... Thank you soooo much!